# Управление спящим режимом пк

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Необходимо реализовать управление спящим режимом пк на c++, у меня вообще нет идей как это реализовать(я только начал изучение с++).

Comment: проблема в том как вызвать спящий режим?

Comment: Да, и как я понял, ещё нужно реализовать изменение параметра "переходить в спящий режим через".

Comment: Все просто. Если у Вас винда, то читайте сайт микрософт в части API спящего режима. Если у вас Линукс, то курите man-ы в части API спящего режима.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 не подскажите где именно  эту часть найти?

Comment: Где найти? Странный вопрос! В интернете конечно. Гуглите и будет Вам счастье. Сам я никогда не работал со спящим режимом, а если бы даже и работал, то конечно не запоминал бы адрес мануалов по этой проблеме. Сейчас каждый сам себе поисковая машина, благо информация вся есть в сети.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/228288/4794368

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <powrprof.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"PowrProf.lib")

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    SetSuspendState(0,1,0);
}
```

и ваша машина спит :)

Подробнее читайте [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/powrprof/nf-powrprof-setsuspendstate).